# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntroConstraints cannot assign

Tags: swift, autolayout

When I write the code: (swift code)

I wrote it to try to fix a layout problem where my label keeps staying in the left corner.

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

I get  this error:

```
"Cannot assign to the result of this expression"
```

My function (Nextlevel is the label I can't get to assign the autoresizing statement):

```
@IBAction func check(sender: AnyObject) {


    var strValue = boxShots.text
    var floatValue = Double((strValue as NSString).integerValue)
    var strValue2 = boxMakes.text
    var floatValue2 = Double((strValue2 as NSString).integerValue)
    var stage = "stage 2"
    var procent = floatValue2 / floatValue * 100
    if floatValue < 99
    {
        stageText.text = "text text";
    }

    else if floatValue > 99 && floatValue2 > 49 && procent > 49.99
    {

        stageText.text = "test text"

    } else {
        stageText.text = "test text"

    }
    if floatValue > 99 && floatValue2 > 49 && procent > 49.99
    {
        nextLevel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nextLevel.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        nextLevel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        nextLevel.userInteractionEnabled = true
        nextLevel.text = "Go to next stage"
        self.view.addSubview(nextLevel)

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        nextLevel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    }

func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("stagethree")
    self.presentViewController(vc as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


}
```

Comment: show more of the code

Comment: `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.userInteractionEnabled = true
            label.text = "Go to next stage"
            self.view.addSubview(labell)
            
            let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
            label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)`

Comment: not sure how to showcase my code in a more nicely vertical view?  (sorry! )
@Wain

Comment: add it to the question, not in a comment - you also need to show the definition of `label`

Comment: I wrote what I thought you meant by definition.

Comment: 4 spaces before the text makes it a code block

Comment: Yea I figured it out now, I forgot another space.

Comment: so are some of those bits of code actually all on the same line in your code? the error suggests that you have 2 things on the same line which shouldn't be

Comment: My @IBOulet definition is written in the beginning of my class. However the other code is written under a function in the class.

Comment: ok, show the whole function, exactly as it exists in Xcode